# How can i stream CCTV camera to iphone from windows

Tags: c++, iphone

I am trying to build an iphone app that connects to an IP camera. The IP camera is windows based to i need to create a server using c++ and then stream the video to the iphone app.

Can anyone tell me the best way in going about this task. I am new to programming so a dummies type guide would help.

Thanks

Inam

Comment: I would stream it over the internet, but that's just me :)

Comment: There won't be a step-by-step guide to implementing your specific application.  I'd break the problem down into smaller elements: a streaming video server on Windows, connecting to that server on the iPhone, and displaying video frames from it on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the ITunes store and download a free app from Avigilon. You won't be able to see any video unless you connect to a system but it'll tell you what ports and user information would be needed. There are gateways and streaming methods involved as well. Not a situation where a new developer will have a lot of success.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather too broad to fit into a comment box. It seems, and correct me if I'm wrong, that you're basically asking for someone to write the applications for you.

Instead, if you're a complete beginner, you'll want to first learn how to program for the plaform.

The StackOverflow question [Howto articles for iPhone development, Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c) will help you get started with programming for the iPhone.

Once you have the basics down, you might then ask more specific questions.